# Convert a raw comma separated file into .xlsx type in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, csv, terminal, command, ram

How do you convert a raw csv file (which has 1.6GB size) into .xlsx type in linux command without opening that file.Since it couldn't be opened by the 2GB ram.so as it need to be converted into xlsx type .

Also Is there any alternative way to process this kinda file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's PHP based...

Pre-requisite: PHP support, ie. php server, use XAMPP...

Go to following link & download:
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Unzip the file & Assuming u unzip it to /etc/phpExcel

Here is the code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */

require_once '/etc/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$file=""; //PATH TO CSV FILE`

// Check prerequisites

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    exit("Please run 06largescale.php first.\n");
}

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');`
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.csv', '.xlsx',$file));
?>
```

Comment: I'm welcome for any help regarding setting up php if any.
Can't assure u abt size issue though.

Comment: Thanks for the help ;-) Anyway I need to try in php as a newbie.I have to do the setup etc...